# add image icon to input tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, tags

I want to add and icon image to an input tag and was wondering if anyone has some input on the topic.

my current input tag:

```
 <input class="glossyBtn"  type="submit" name="button" style="vertical-align: middle" value="Select"/>
```

my image that i want to add to the input so it will be to the left of the text (Value):

```
<img alt="" style="vertical-align: middle" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/images/user.png")%>" />
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set that image as the `background` of the `glossyBtn` css class.

*Change the image path with your local image.*

```
.glossyBtn
{
    background-image:url('http://i50.tinypic.com/20keohf.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:left top;  padding-left:15px;
}
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/6Nfvz/13/

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I made some alterations making the above properties in their own class so that my class is "glossyBtn addIcon" and added the same to addIcon:hover. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the image needs to be clickable you can build out a more complex control:

http://jsfiddle.net/NXAuT/1/

```
<div class="con">
    <input type="text" />
    <img src="MY_IMAGE.PNG" />
</div>​

.con { width:180px; position:relative; border:1px solid #ccc; }
.con input { margin:0 0 0 4px; border:0; }
.con img { display:block; position:absolute; top:4px; left:164px; cursor:pointer; }​

$(".con img").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});​
```

If the image doesn't have a click event associated to it then follow the advice by others and include it as a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. please set image path and padding accordingly

```
.glossyBtn {
background:url(../Content/images/user.png) left top no-repeat;
padding-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: when i tried this the background of the whole input is turned white. When i try to add background-size: 16px 16px it still doesn't have an affect. I don't want the background color to change

Answer (score 0):

Set the image using `background` in glossyBtn and also try `background-size` for adding height and width...